# Controlling indents in Go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I have the following Go template:

```
{{ range $job, $steps := .jobs -}}
    {{ $job -}}:
    {{ range $steps -}}
        {{ . }}
    {{ end }}
{{- end }}
```

It's producing output that looks like the following:

```
job1:
    step1
    step2
    job2:  <--- This should not be indented
    step1
    step2
```

All jobs after `job1` are indented four spaces. It's not apparent to me why the template engine would decide to arbitrarily indent the remaining jobs. How can I control indentation so that the output appears as so:

```
job1:
    step1
    step2
job2:
    step1
    step2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`job2`'s identation does not come from where you think: it comes from the spaces and newline between printing the steps:

```
{{ range $steps -}}
   {{ . }}  <-- starting from here, and the indentation of the next line
{{ end }}
```

So the newline and the indentation after `step2` of `job1` is outputted, and you start `job2` right there: already indented.

If you insert newlines and indentation only where you want them in the output, you get what you want:

```
{{ range $job, $steps := .jobs}}{{ $job }}:{{ range $steps }}
    {{ . }}{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Or format your template the way you want, and disable indentation everywhere, and explicitly output newlines and indentation where you want them:

```
{{ range $job, $steps := .jobs -}}
    {{- $job -}}:{{"\n"}}
    {{- range $steps -}}
        {{"    "}}{{- . -}}{{"\n"}}
    {{- end -}}
{{- end }}
```

Or a third solution:

```
{{ range $job, $steps := .jobs -}}
    {{ $job }}:
    {{- range $steps }}
    {{ . }}{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

These all output (try them on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1j3TXXoY5tA)):

```
job1:
    step1
    step2
job2:
    step1
    step2
```